# How to retrieve first level Object in AWS S3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I want to retrieve top level objects only.

```
object1/f1/
object2/s2/
object3/
```

I want to list out only object1, object2, object3.  Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried doing it with s3 node package but it seems the "recursive" parameter is not working properly. Also AWS sdk's listObjects() don't have any option to stop getting the files recursively.

Answer (score -1):

```
s3.listObjects({Bucket: "bucket_name", Delimiter:"/"});
```

Return me the JSON repsonse which contains the CommonPrefixes which gives me top level objects

Comment: It will give all the files  after the delimiter